# Ideas for a Closed form for $ \sum_{k=0}^n k10^k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, closed-form

Is there a closed formula for this summation:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n k10^k, $$
where $n\in\mathbb{N}$? I would like to learn trick o strategies for this kind of problems.

Comment: Multiply by $(1-10)^2=1-2\cdot 10+10^2$ and cancel terms with the same exponent of $10$.

Comment: Your best friend(s) are the closed-form(s) for the geometric series: $\sum_{k=0}^n r^k = (1-r^{n+1})/(1-r)$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k = 1/(1-r)$. From there, you can invoke the power rule for differentiation/integration to derive as many of these formulas as you like.

Comment: How did you get to that?

Comment: Another way could be to apply [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts), in which the factor $k$ gets differentiated and the factor $10^n$ gets added.

Comment: Fearfulsymmetry, that was my first attempt but I failed. Shall I derive with respect to r?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence#Sum_of_the_terms).

Comment: @Senna yep. Ask yourself: if I have something that looks like $k r^k$, where did the $k$ come from? Ans: power rule. It's instructive to work out the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}k10^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(k+1)10^{k} - \sum_{k=0}^{n}10^{k}
\end{align*}

**EDIT**

In order to obtain the desired result, notice that
\begin{align*}
s_{n}(x) = 1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + \ldots + x^{n} & \Rightarrow s_{n}(x)x = x + x^{3} + \ldots + x^{n+1}\\\\
& \Rightarrow s_{n}(x) - s_{n}(x)x = 1 - x^{n+1}\\\\
& \Rightarrow s_{n}(x)(1 - x) = 1 - x^{n+1}\\\\
& \Rightarrow s_{n}(x) = \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1 - x}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is your second summation. I can't manage it. I was trying some derivative to the famous formula of geometric serie sum.

Comment: @Senna I have edited my answer. Hopefully this is helpful this time.

Comment: Thank you. I already solved the problem. But you deserve a +1 for your help and edit!

Comment: @Senna You can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the summation to start from $k=1$. Then
$$ s\cdot \frac{d}{ds} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} s^k = s \cdot \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k s^{k-1} =\sum\limits_{k=0}^n ks^k. $$
Now, the left hand side has a nice closed expression that we can then evaluate at $s=10$, can you find the closed expression?

Comment: Yeah, thank you! +1

Answer (score 1):

For $x \gt 0$, you have

$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n x^k = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1} - 1$$ hence

$$x f^\prime_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n k x^k$$ and therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k 10^k = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\right) (10)$$

Comment: This was exactly the idea I have on mind... But couldn't finish it. Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

Many answers have used the derivative method, but you can also do it this way:
Let $S$ be your required summation. Write $10S$ and subtract from $S$. You would get a GP series which is easily evaluated.